# Session timeout the first few times but work later

Tags: asp.net, session, internet-explorer-8

I have ASP.NET website running on IIS 7 server. I use a session on a page that gets retrieved on another. When I publish the code and run my website, the first few times the session is givign me null value, but after one of couple of times it starts working and then continue working afterwards.

I've seen different behaviors when it is IE7 or IE8. Even within IE8, sometimes it works in compatibility view or not. This is completely random, but the only common behavior is that when it works, it starts working afterward.

We are using SQL mode for SessionState.

What seems to be the problem? What can I do to get down to the root cause?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show us some of the session code you are using

Comment: change your session to default InProc and try it there first to make sure it works.

Comment: how you have setup the session and the cookies on your web config ?

Comment: please note that this works fine at firefox. Here is the web.config settings:

Comment: this code works well at firefox and most of the time in IE 7. My web.config settings: <sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="<connectionstring>" cookieless="false" timeout="20" /> and at the page load, I try to retrieve the session like so: MyData md = (MyData)Session["myData"]; and this is the line that breaks. My issue is almost exact to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956374/session-not-sticking-for-asp-net-mvc2-in-iis7-5-in-ie8/9083873#9083873